# Slow Loading of CoreNLP Annotators

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am writing a program that utilizes Stanford's CoreNLP, it is taking about 1 minute every time that I run it using eclipse. I know that this is normal since a lot of training models needs to be loaded.

I just want to know if there is any way that can be used to pre-load all annotators instead of having to wait each time I compile my program.

Answer (score 2):

If your program is going to construct a Stanford CoreNLP pipeline at start up you're out of luck.  You could re-engineer it to use the Stanford CoreNLP server and make server requests, then you could just have the server running in the background and when your program loads up it will start immediately without the 1 minute delay to load models.

Comment: Here is some info on the server: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html